# Mac OS - Deployd - mongod fails to start

Tags: mongodb, deployd

I'm trying to use Deployd on my Mac. I've installed mongoDB and added it's bin folder to my $PATH - mongod runs perfectly with my user. The problem appears when I try to run Deployd, mongod fails to run.
I runned it with `DEBUG=* dpd`and the results I've got are:

```
starting deployd v0.8.0...
  mongod starting mongod +0ms
  mongod <Buffer 32 30 31 35 2d 30 33 2d 31 32 54 31 39 3a 34 30 3a 34 31 2e 30 36 30 2b 30 31 30 30 20 49 20 43 4f 4e 54 52 4f 4c 20 20 5b 69 6e 69 74 61 6e 64 6c 69 ... > +158ms
  mongod <Buffer 32 30 31 35 2d 30 33 2d 31 32 54 31 39 3a 34 30 3a 34 31 2e 30 36 30 2b 30 31 30 30 20 49 20 43 4f 4e 54 52 4f 4c 20 20 5b 69 6e 69 74 61 6e 64 6c 69 ... > +2ms
  server started with options {"port":2403,"db":{"host":"127.0.0.1","port":4660,"name":"-deployd"},"env":"development"} +44ms
  socket.io:server initializing namespace / +0ms
  socket.io:server creating engine.io instance with opts {"log level":0,"path":"/socket.io"} +1ms
  socket.io:server attaching client serving req handler +1ms
  mongod <Buffer 32 30 31 35 2d 30 33 2d 31 32 54 31 39 3a 34 30 3a 34 31 2e 31 30 36 2b 30 31 30 30 20 49 20 4e 45 54 57 4f 52 4b 20 20 5b 69 6e 69 74 61 6e 64 6c 69 ... > +5ms
  internal-resources constructed +10ms
listening on port 2403
type help for a list of commands
dpd >   mongod error: 1 +757ms
  mongod killing mongod +0ms
Failed to start MongoDB (Make sure 'mongod' are in your $PATH or use dpd --mongod option. Ref: http://docs.deployd.com/docs/basics/cli.html)
```

The only way I've got deploy to run is with `sudo dpd -d`. I've changed /data/db's ownership from root to my user. I also changed the ownership of mongod and ./mongodb/bin.

Does someone knows what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem here. I tried @bpirvu's solution, but it didn't work. Did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the path to your mongod executable via the '-m' parameter

```
dpd -m /path/to/mongod/
```

as described here http://docs.deployd.com/docs/basics/cli.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured there are no extra `mongo.lock` and local files in your data folder. 
I had the same issue and deleting these extra files solved the problem.

(I think these are generated when mongo is shut down ungracefully).